# Semidirect Product of Two Groups

Tags: abstract-algebra

So I am beginning to learn Semidirect product. Now I have to identify the semidirect  product of the two groups $Z_{p}\times Z_{p}$ =$H$ and $K$=$Z_{p}$ where  p is  an  odd prime.
So I can write $H$=$<a>\times <b>$ and $K$=$<x>$ .And since $Aut(H)$ has a function of  order p  so we  have a non-trivial  homomorphism $\phi$ from $K$ into $Aut(H)$. So there  is  a  semidirect product that $H\times_{\phi} K$ that is not isomorphic  to  the direct product $H\times K$. Now the product looks  like $$(h_{1},k_{1})(h_{2},k_{2}) = (h_{1}k_{1}.h_{2} , k_{1}k_{2})$$  where . is the  action  of  $K$  on $H$ determined by $\phi$.

Upto this I can think  of  from  the  basic theory about semidirect product construction I  have learnt.But to  identify  the  group  I need to  know exactly how $K$  is  acting  on $H$  i.e  what are $x.a$  and $x.b$ in terms  of $a$  and $b$. Should I choose  any  arbitrary  automorphism of  $H$ or is there any rule  which  automorphism should  be  chosen here? Please help.

I  was  trying  inversion as the automorphism i.e  $x.a=a^{-1}$ and $x.b=b^{-1}$
So  the group  is generated  by ${a,b,x}$ such that $x^{p}=a^{p}=b^{p}=1$ and $xax^{-1}=a^{-1}$ and $xbx^{-1}=b^{-1}$. Is that a valid group or isomorphic to some  known group?

Answer (score 2):

In general, semi-direct products are not unique, as there may be many choices for the automorphism $\phi$. For example, when $p = 3$, the automorphism group has order $48$ and there are $4$ such automorphisms.

In this case ($p =3$, which may extend to the general case), we may take (for example):

$\phi_1(a,b) = (a+b,b)$, so that $\phi_k(a,b) = (a+kb,b)$.

Thus $((h_1,h_2),k)\ast((h_1',h_2'),k') = ((h_1 + h_1' + kh_2',h_2+h_2'),k+k')$.

This group is a non-abelian group of order $27$, one can see that:

$((0,1),1)\ast((1,0),1) = ((0+1+1\cdot0,1+0),1+1) = ((1,1),2)$ whereas:

$((1,0),1)\ast((0,1),1) = ((1+0+1\cdot1,1+0),1+1) = ((2,1),2)$

Comment: So does  that  mean the answer  I got  by  taking  inversion as the  automorphism $\phi$ is one of the correct  answer? Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Inversion is an involution, that it is to say it has order $2$, so no element of a group of order $p$ (if $p$ is an *odd* prime) can map to it under a homomorphism. It *will* work for $p = 2$, but in $\Bbb Z_2 \times \Bbb Z_2$ every element is its own additive inverse, and we get a direct product, since the inversion automorphism *is* the identity map.